# Is there an accepted way to omit a parameter from a function/method?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, parameters

Let's say (hypothetically) I have an object constructor `MyObj`, which has a method like this:

```
MyObj.prototype.method = function(x, y){
    x = x || this.x; //default value
    y = y || this.y;
}
```

What if I want `x` to default to `this.x`? This is what I came up with:

```
var object = new MyObj();
var omit = 0; //I don't think the first two
    omit = ''; // values would even default?
    omit = null;
    omit = undefined;
object.method(omit, 5);
```

The question is: is there a best practice or accepted method of omitting a parameter from a function?

Comment: `undefined` seems cleaner, as it's what you get when you don't pass the argument at all. But I think the code would be more obvious with `undefined` than with `omit`, especially for occasional readers/maintainers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most often, when you feel the need to define such a placeholder, what you'd really need is to use an options objects :

```
object.method({y: 5});
```

Note that using `x = x || this.x;` doesn't allow for falsy values. That's why I usually do

```
function method(opt) {
   var x = (opt && 'x' in opt) ? opt.x : defaultValue;
   ...
}
```

When you really need to pass an `undefined` value, then I think that `undefined` is the most obvious solution. And most obvious most often means easiest to maintain.

Comment: @alex23 Well, you always have to check before usage, there is no difference here.

Comment: Wouldn't `(opt && "x" in opt)` (or even get rid of the `opt &&` part too) make more sense? Otherwise you couldn't explicitly pass `undefined`

Comment: @ian yes it would. Didn't think about it (it's an old code I reuse)... I edit.

Comment: @dystroy There are several ways to "check" for stuff like this, I was just wondering :)

Comment: Options object in combination with `extend({}, defaults, options)` seems to be a good convention.

Comment: Does this pass a temporary object that is locally scoped to the function? (I guess the bigger question there is: is a parameter passed to a function stored as a local variable to that function?)

Comment: @BillyMathews I you declare the object, just as in my example, then yes. But you might declare an options objects elsewhere and reuse it.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyObj.prototype.method = function(x, y){
    x = typeof x == 'undefined' ? this.x : x; //default value
    y = typeof y == 'undefined' ? this.y : y;
}

var object = new MyObj();
object.method(undefined, 5);// pass undefined
```

Comment: Note that this approach isn't suitable if you want x or y to be able to have any "falsy" values (0, "", false etc)

Comment: @Sushil In this case it is easier just to check for `undefined` with `x === undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to find that using `null` is the most cross language friendly. It's just a matter of preference, but I prefer to write the literal `null` value as anything else could be defined somewhere else in the code. (Even `undefined` can be set to some value.)

```
MyObj.prototype.method = function(x, y){
    x = x || this.x; //default value
    y = y || this.y;
}

var object = new MyObj();
object.method(null, 5);
```